# Vertically aligning text in the center of table cell

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I know that similar problem have been asked and answered previously on this site, but unfortunately none of the answers have been able to help.

I need my text to vertically align in the center/ bottom of my table row. This i my css text:

```
h3 {
    vertical-align:bottom;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding-top: 0px;
    background: url(images/bg3.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:left bottom;}
```

Comment: `vertical-align:middle`?

Comment: can you please upload to http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: what is 'vertically align in the center/ bottom' ? is it center or is it bottom?

Answer (score 3):

If your text is single line, than use `line-height` = `height`:

```
h3 {
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 30px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `align` and `valign` properties in your table cell:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td height="300" align="center" valign="middle">
            <h3>Hello World</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rarzwuoo/).

Comment: I don't think he wanna use table.

Comment: @Benjamin In the title of question, OP wrote **table cell**.

Comment: @ROX true, though valign is a deprecated property.. better stick with vertical-align.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems you want to vertically align to the bottom and horizontally to the center.. if that is true you should do this:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tvjjqcsx/)

```
td    { text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom;}
```

***Notice the styles need to be on the table cell and not on the inner element (h3)**

good luck!